# WebApi OWIN same token valid for two different instances of service

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have created WebApi selfhost service using OWIN library. Everything works great except some problem with authentication. I have started two instances of the service on the server and it came out that the token obtained from one service is valid for the second service!  As I know the token is verified by  OWIN using some protection key. The questions are:

1. How to make key invalid for the other instance of service? I have tried to generate custom keys using Generate-MachineKey but the result is the same.
2. What is the protection key the OWIN uses? Is it stored somewhere?
3. Does this key differ for different applications?

The setup:

```
var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(accessTokenExipreMinutes),
    Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
    AllowInsecureHttp = allowInsecureHttp
};

appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerTokens(oAuthOptions);
```

The authorization server provider:

```
class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out string clientId, out string clientSecret);

        var result = Validate(clientId, clientSecret);
        if (result)
        {
            context.Validated(clientId);
            return;
        }

        context.Rejected();
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, props);

            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Rejected();
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` there is a property called `AccessTokenFormat` which convert `AuthenticationTicket` to `byte[]` and vise versa. This option encrypt the token. You can set this option with different keys for different instances of application so they can't read each other's token.

This is how you set `AccessTokenFormat`

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection; 
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler;

IDataProtector dataProtecter = app.CreateDataProtector("YOUR_KEY");
var ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TicketDataFormat = ticketDataFormat
};
```

The default of Owin is that it use your Machine Key for creating `TicketDataFormat`, so you can also set different Machine Key in `web.config` for your instances.

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Additional information - above code requires two namespaces: Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection; Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler;

Comment: I can't use Machine Key because it is self-hosted app